# How take data from json response in angularjs

Tags: php, json, angularjs

hello everyone i have some issue 
in my controller i do http post to server and run of the server some file with php server side language and check if i the user is register in mydb
this is my code:

```
 $scope.sendPost = function()
 {
    var login = 
        'mylogin='+ JSON.stringify({
            email: $scope.email,
            pass:  $scope.pass
        })

       $http({

          method : 'POST',
                    url : 'http://igortestk.netai.net/login.php',
                    data: login,
                   Content-Type:'text/plain', 
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  
                  }).success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);



                    console.log(resultlogin);
                        console.log(json);



                    }).error(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
               })
```

from the sever side i back json_encode in php of some status of login
so my question is how i take the json value from the server response 
this is my server response :

```
{"statuslogin":1}]
```

edit: this is my server side code in php;

```
$query="select * from `User` where Email='$email' and Pass='$pass'";

$result=mysql_query($query ,$con);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){

    $reponse['statuslogin']=1;
}
else{
    $reponse['statuslogin']=0;
}

$output=json_encode($reponse);

print $output;
```

edit2:

ok it's doesnt work beacuse the data of the response is a string and data[0] i get "[" this bracket : data: "[{"statuslogin":1}]" so maybe some other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value with:

```
console.log(data.statuslogin);
```

In case of one array:

```
console.log(data[0].statuslogin);
```

---

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://igortestk.netai.net/login.php",
    data: login,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
}).success(function (data) {

    console.log(data[0].statuslogin); // In the console will print: 1

    // If you need to show a message according the result, you can do this:

    $scope.message = (data[0].statuslogin === 1) ? "Login success" : "Login error, please check";

}).error(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

However, according the AngularJS Documentation, the success method is deprecated:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Then, you might use the standard form with the shortcut form, by using then(). Something like this:

```
$http.post("http://igortestk.netai.net/login.php", data, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }}).then(function(response)
{
    console.log(response.data[0].statuslogin); // In the console will print: 1
}, function(response)
{
    console.log(response);
});
```

**Demo**

*PHP File: loginajax.php*

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

$reponse['statuslogin']=1;

$output=json_encode($reponse);

echo $output;
flush();
?>
```

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$http",
    function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.email = "email@server.com";
      $scope.pass = "123456";

      var login =
        'mylogin=' + JSON.stringify({
          email: $scope.email,
          pass: $scope.pass
        });


      $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://dfjb.webcindario.com/loginajax.php",
        data: login,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      }).success(function(data) {

        console.log(data.statuslogin); // In the console will print: 1

        // If you need to show a message according the result, you can do this:

        //$scope.message = (data[0].statuslogin === 1) ? "Login success" : "Login error, please check";

      }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body data-ng-controller="Controller">
</body>

</html>
```

In the network tab of Google Chrome console, i have this json response:

[image]

Comment: the data is my data? i pass to server?

Comment: No, the data contains the response of your server. When you use .success(data) AngularJS expose the results through the data variable. In this context, data is an object.

Comment: As you're getting an array from your server, you can use:
**data[0].statuslogin** to get the value.

Comment: ok it's doesnt work beacuse the data of the response is a string and data[0]  i get "[" this bracket : data: "[{"statuslogin":1}]" so maybe some other solution ?

Comment: Ok, please, can you show in your question your full json of the response, in the Network tab in Google Chrome? We can iterate over the data object and inner properties to display the result, finally.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a live demo using php and AngularJS. Btw in my php file i have: header("Content-Type: application/json");

Comment: {"sLog":1} this is my full json response 
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/dnzwk9l6v/image.png this is my full response from the server

Comment: Ok, you need to run your web from localhost server. Example:  **http://localhost/MyProject**. The $http service runs over XMLHttpRequest object.

However, the json response is returning a json with html tag from the other server.

{"sLog":1}
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code --> <script type="text/javascript" src="stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>; <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

The proper way is the json response with only: {"sLog":1}. Check my answer.

Comment: oh ok i try it's out tommorow and let you know if it's working :} thank you dude

Comment: ok dude the php server code i need run also in localhost? if i want run it on web server what i need to do?

Comment: You might try installing AppServ in your pc. http://www.appservnetwork.com/

So, you can open the Web in the Browser with this url: http://localhost/MyProject

Answer (score 1):

The better way to access *JSON* data service is with **ngResource** which can be used to consume Restful API in AngularJs.

```
.factory('UserService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:user',{user: "@user"});
});
```

To perform Resource get just do:

```
$scope.users = UserService.query();
```

resource object has the following methods:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

To get a specific user:

```
$scope.oneUser = UserService.get({user: 1});
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

`$http('http://igortestk.netai.net/login.php').post(data).then(function(data){ if(data.statuslogin === 1){alert('welcome');} });`

Comment: Object {data: "[{"statuslogin":0}] this object i got but i cant take the value from statuslogin

Comment: your data is in array .. if so then data[0].statuslogin will give you the login status